How to create body mass index (BMI) calculation in laravel
I am beginner in laravel. I don't know how to implement the BMI (body Mass Index) calculation in laravel framework.
In my route (web.php) i wrote
Route::post('/sciences/cancer/cancerHome', 'CalculateControler@hitungseri')->name('hitungseri');
Route::get('/sciences/cancer/cancerHome', 'CalculateControler@hitungseri');
In my controller I wrote
public function hitungseri(Request $request){    
$tbseri = $request->get('tinggibadan');    
$bbseri = $request->get('beratbadan');    
$bmi = $bbseri / ($tbseri * $tbseri);        
return view('/sciences/cancer/cancerHome',['bmi' => $bmi]);

an in my blade.php I wrote
<div>    <h1>Hitung Kemoterapi Seri</h1>   
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('hitungseri') }}">       
@csrf       
<div class="row mb-3">         
<label for="tinggibadan" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Tinggi Badan (cm)') }}</label>
         
<div class="col-md-6">            
<input name="tinggibadan" type="number" step="0.01" id="tinggibadan" type="tinggibadan" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="tinggibadan" value="{{ old('tinggibadan') }}" required autocomplete="tinggibadan" autofocus>
            
@error('tinggibadan')                
<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">                    
<strong>{{ $message }}</strong>                
</span>            
@enderror         
</div>       
</div>
       

<div class="row mb-3">           
<label for="beratbadan" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Berat Badan (Kg)') }}</label>
             
<div class="col-md-6">               
<input name="beratbadan" type="number" step="0.01" id="beratbadan" type="beratbadan" class="form-control @error('beratbadan') is-invalid 
@enderror" name="beratbadan" required autocomplete="beratbadan">
                
@error('beratbadan')                 
<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">                    
<strong>{{ $message }}</strong>                 
</span>                
@enderror             

</div>          
</div>    
</form>    

<div class="row mb-0">    
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">        
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">            
{{ __('Hitung') }}        </button>        
<span></span>      
<input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" type="reset">   
</div>  
</div>
  
<div>    
<p>{{ $bmi }}</p>  
</div>

I am receiving this error: Undefined variable  $bmi at blade.php
I don't whats is wrong. please help me

There are multiple mistakes in your code. For example: while loading the form, the request is empty.  this would result in a division by zero error? I would personally have a separate function for the post request. Use an @if statement to check if the variable exists and if you really want to use the same controller function for the post and get request, check if there is something posted before you calculate the bmi. Also when you load a view in laravel, you should use the dot notation view('folder.subfolder.bladefile')

As @GertB. said, you should use . and give it the path of the blade file. Be aware that you are using the view function and you are sending a variable to the page to be displayed. You probably made a mistake with route func! We use this function when we want to send parameters to route. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#required-parameters

I'am so sorry, I am beginner in laravel. I Try use dot in controller like this but still got a same error 'return view('sciences.cancer.cancerHome',['bmi' => $bmi]);' Could you give me a sample. Thank you
